# Setting correct position with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use this as a way to center the "HOME" image into the first cell. I am close but it keeps acting weird. Also...how can I make it so the button will open a link? current look attached.

CSS and HTML since I cant "post more than 2 links.": https://hastebin.com/raw/obibotiket

[what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NykDz.png)

Comment: Your "fhnav" has a padding bottom of 40px: So "homeBtn" should have a margin-top: 40px;

Comment: @BlessingOni That just moved the whole nav down

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: "Also..." — please limit yourself to one question per question. Asking multiple questions makes it hard to give a good, complete answer (or close the question if a duplicate can be found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.fhNav {
  width: 893px;
  height: 90px;
  background: url(../images/navBack.png);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.homeBtn{
  width: 137px;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 12px;
  background: url("../images/navbtn/homebtn.png") no-repeat;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px red solid;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.homeBtn a{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fhNav" id="nav">
  <div class="homeBtn">
      <a href="https://www.factionhouse.org/"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the button to be clickable try this

```
.homeBtn a{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey man that seemed to have done the trick..can you explain why it wasn't clickable before and how what you said made it clickable and line up right with a few minor tweaks? Thanks!

Comment: It was click but it was extremely small because there was no text and its size was as big as the space so it was almost not existent. Setting those four to 0 would have stretched it out to the size of `homeBtn`

Comment: @Josh Thanks for the explanation. Also..why wasn't it lining up before?

Comment: You needed a `margin-top: 40px` like me and Blessing Oni had in the `homeBtn` div; that's why it didn't align.

Comment: @Squallz I couldn't have explained much better as josh did. Happy happy it helped

Answer (score -1):

for your first question, I suggest you make a div for each cell inside your ".fhNav".
for the second question make button inside your a tag

```
<div class="fhNav">
    <div class="cell">
        <a href="#"><button>Home</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```